# Is it ok to leave out my country of residence?

Tags: resume, hiring-process, ethics

I would like to know if it's ok to not show my current country of residence in my resume?

I know by experience, that most recruiter would prefer hiring people from the same state/country and I would like to avoid being excluded from the get go.

I am not saying that I want to hide this information, it is visible on my blog, Linkedin page, about me page, on the education section and also on the work experience... I just want the reader to first see that I'm worthy before he gets to know that I require relocation.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not OK. Depending on the countries involved, hiring a non-native may be a SERIOUS burden on the employer. It's fine for them to take that burden on if they want, but trying to get partway through the hiring process before springing that detail on them is rude, and will probably lose you the job anyway.

Comment: Agreed, finding out about relo or visa requirements late in the game is a dealbreaker.

Comment: The purpose is not to hide the information. As I said, this is mentioned later on the resume (I even have a declaration on the bottom stating that I do need a visa) but whether or not I should put it on the header of the resume where it will be the first thing that a reader will notice.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with 'No'.

The reason is simple. If you get a quick yes, you pretty much have to mention about your location to arrange when you are to start anyway. Depending on the job you apply for, some might want you in-house ASAP, and then you're in a slight amount of trouble.

You are also expected to be honest on your resume, and while leaving details out isn't lying per se, it can still be seen as a negative thing. Your papers can be filled with details about experience and recommendations, but your papers matter little until they've actually had you in for an interview, face to face. And don't bother with adding linkedin, blog links or website links, they are not too likely to check it out, as judgement usually falls during interview. The more shiny you seem to be, the more likely they will try and test to see if you actually are that good, or just a punk who has blown his papers way out of proportions.

In short, add it. The worst that can happen is you'll get a 'No' from them. They will rarely say exactly *why*, either. Getting a few negative answers is just your everyday part of being someone who is looking for a job.

Answer (score 3):

Your question asks if the *resume* needs to include this, and I think that it does not -- so yes, it's ok to omit it *there*.  However, as others have said, it's rude to start down the application path without disclosing information that a company might consider to be a deal-breaker.  So you have to tell them, but you don't necessarily need to do it on the resume if you don't want to for some reason.

This is where the cover letter comes in.  In the cover letter, after your pitch, you say something like "I currently live in $location and am open to relocation".  If you do not need relocation assistance for some reason, say so -- you've just gotten less expensive.  (Maybe you're going to be moving to the target location anyway, for instance.  Maybe your spouse already has a new job there with relocation.)

Further, for all but the smallest companies, there is likely to be a formal application that you have to fill out.  This will ask for your current address, among other things.

If you are are only concerned about being rejected by the initial HR screener, then this really doesn't make a difference -- do what I advised or just put it on the resume.  But if you fear that your location might influence *other* reviewers (e.g. because of prejudices), you can do what I've suggested and leave it off of the resume.  The resume will be passed around; the cover letter might not be and the application generally won't be (at least in my experience).  When I (technical person, not HR) am given a resume to review I don't care about where the candidate is coming from (not my problem), only what he can do, and I've reviewed resumes that only included an email address without blinking.  My own resume does not include a physical location and this doesn't appear to be hindering me (though I am not open to relocation, and say so if applying to a company with locations outside my own city).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you rather weed out the comapnies that are unwilling to go through the process to hire from another country before you wate much time on them?